# CMake: interface library that has different flags when used from C or C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, cmake, objective-c++

I'm working on a single-header library (https://github.com/zserge/webview).

I use CMake (https://github.com/zserge/webview/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) as a default build system for C and C++. I use `INTERFACE` type of the target, because my library is only a single C header.
Since the library is cross-platform, some of the parts have to be written in Objective-C for MacOS.

Currently, I define `target_compile_options` for the library, where I add `-x objective-c` for MacOS builds, so that the caller would not worry about this build flag anymore.

But if I want to use this library from a C++ project - I need to provide `-x objective-c++` instead. If I add this compile option for the executable that uses the `INTERFACE` library - the command line gets mixed up incorrectly, e.g. `-x objective-c objective-c++` and it results in an error.

I wonder what would be the best solution here? Is it possible to provide different sets of options to the `INTERFACE` library depending on the caller language (C vs C++)? Or is there a way to override an `INTERFACE` library compile flags from the main executable?

Comment: I can use `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` instead, but I still hope there is a better solution.

Comment: You are actually using this "header" file as a translation unit. It would be definitely better to properly split it into several separate files. Right now this file is a crazy mix of 3 languages.

Comment: @VTT It is, indeed. A mix of C99 and Obj-C in one apple-specific section. I have a dream of rewriting Obj-C using objc runtime in C one day. To be honest, I don't really support the idea of splitting it into several files/translation units because the main usage of the library is from the other languages such as Go, Rust, Python etc. And each of them has its own "build system" for C extensions. So as long as the library is single-header - it's very easy to create bindings and to integrate it.

Comment: The problem here is that you're using INTERFACE improperly. Why don't you create a "module" of your library... the output is a C library (mix c and obj-c) that can be used from c/c++ projects.

Comment: @elvis.dukaj Sorry, I'm still new to CMake. To my shame I struggle to find a nice tutorial on how to make modules with CMake. I understand that I can drop webview as an INTERFACE library (those who need it as a single-header lib probably don't use CMake anyway), and provide static/shared libraries instead. That should work. But how modules are different? Are they a more convenient way to use static/shared libraries with CMake?

Comment: @elvis.dukaj From my understanding, `add_library(MODULE)` can't be linked to, it's a dynamic library that acts like a plugin and should be loaded at runtime. Is that what you meant? I don't really see how it helps, sorry. I think a static/shared library fits much better in my case.